# Spark: spark-submit getting packages like pandas out to all the nodes through spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, conda

I have a spark job that runs pyspark. I can pass in a script that it will execute with whatever other parameters (e.g. executor-memory, driver-cores) `spark-submit spark-test1.py --executor-memory 10G --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 12G --driver-cores 8`.

Note - I'm going to use pandas in the below example, but it is not limited to just pandas. Could be any arbitrary package or number of packages that need to be passed to each node.

When I have the command in my script `import pandas as pd` the job fails. `ImportError: No module named panda`.

Now, can I either pass in some kind of `--` argument a conda environment that has pandas installed or can I add a path to the panadas package?

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you don't want to bootstrap a pip install command on each node to install all the packages directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the egg file by using the --py-files command. So your command will looks like -
spark-submit spark-test1.py --executor-memory 10G --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 12G --driver-cores 8 --py-files

Comment: Can you add details on how you include all the dependencies in the egg file? It is straightforward to build the egg but the nodes on the cluster will still have to install all the dependencies.